# ¿Como combinar dos objetos en un sólo con PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo los siguiente objetos.

```
[{"id":430,"suscriptor_id":7,"diario_id":430,"subcuentad_id":24}]  
   [{"id":43,"suscriptor_id":7,"diario_id":43,"subcuentad_id":0,"subcuentah_id":24,"importeh":"9130.00"}]
```

Mi idea es combinar sus elementos de manera que pueda obtener un sólo objeto del tipo siguiente

```
[{"suscriptor_id":7,"subcuentad_id":24,"subcuentah_id":24,"importeh":"9130.00"}]
```

¿Hay algún método para hacerlo?,lo he intentado con array merge pero no funciona
Gracias

Comment: Eso no son dos objetos. Son dos arrays y cada uno de ellos tiene un objeto. Prueba primero a extraerlos a objeto, y luego convertirlos a array.

Comment: Perdona la insistencia,debo tener un problema de conceptos;si ya son dos arrays,no entiendo la idea   de convertirlos en un objeto,para después pasarlos a lo que ya son

Comment: No, lo siento, culpa mía, no me explique bien. Lo que quise decir es que tienes dos arrays, cada uno contiene un objeto. Primero tienes que extraer cada objeto, y luego juntarlos o crear el nuevo objeto a partir de estos. Lo suyo quizás sería convertir esos objetos de nuevo a array para usar el array_merge, pero si ya conoces tú tipo de objeto y como debe ser la mezcla, con asignar propiedades de uno en otro debería bastar